# A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'RenderBox'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build a very simple paint application in the flutter. I am getting the "***A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'RenderBox'.***" error.

I am attaching the code below, the error is at line 18 (i.e. at RenderBox object = context.findRenderObject();)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class drawPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _drawPageState createState() => new _drawPageState();
}

class _drawPageState extends State<drawPage> {
  List<Offset> _points = <Offset>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
        child: new GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
            setState(() {
              RenderBox object = context.findRenderObject();
              Offset _localPosition =
                  object.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
              _points = new List.from(_points)..add(_localPosition);
            });
          },
          onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) => _points.add(Offset.zero),
          child: new CustomPaint(
            painter: new Signature(points: _points),
            size: Size.infinite,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () => _points.clear(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Signature extends CustomPainter {
  List<Offset> points;

  Signature({this.points});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 10.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      if (points[i] != Offset.zero && points[i + 1] != Offset.zero) {
        canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], paint);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(Signature oldDelegate) => oldDelegate.points != points;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
RenderBox object = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
```

we should cast generic type to definite type, please refer to t[his official link](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system#generic-type-assignment)

Comment: Amazing, this worked for an argument I'm passing to my named route.  On the receiving end in main.dart: `final Coupon? coupon = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Coupon;`